# ROS on foxboardg20

Tags: cross-compiling

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I would like to install ros on my foxboard g20 (http://www.acmesystems.it/FOXG20).
my foxboardg20 is based on arm processor and debian squeeze.

Please, could you tell me more on the installation instructions?

How can i get the source code package? (where is the source code?)
How cross-compiling for this target?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30009/ros-on-foxboardg20/) by [biglosr](https://answers.ros.org/users/2013/biglosr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Compiling from source is explained here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source.

Or look at eros, cross compilation is also explained there: http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0